# Coffeescript 'this' inside jQuery .each()

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have some coffeescript like the following:

```
class foo:
    @bar = 'bob loblaw'

    processRows: ->
        $("#my-table>tr").each ->
            id = $(this).attr("id")
            @processRow id

    processRow: (id) ->
        console.log @bar + id
```

So my problem is: I need `this` to reference the `.each` context inside the loop to get at `id`, but I also would like `this` to reference the class instance inside `foo.processRow()`---which it does not currently do.

Using something like `_this = this` outside the `.each` function and passing it around isn't a great solution, either, since I reference many class variables inside `processRow`.

Any thoughts? Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Answer (score 130, accepted):

[`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) passes the current element as second parameter of the callback, so you don't *have* to reserve `this` for jQuery:

```
processRows: ->
    $("#my-table>tr").each (index, element) =>
        id = $(element).attr("id")
        @processRow id
```

Notice the use of the **[*fat arrow* (`=>`) syntax](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#fat_arrow)** for the callback function; it binds the function's context to the current value of `this`. (`this` in the callback function is always the same `this` as the one at the time you defined the function.)

Comment: The **fat arrow syntax** did the trick for me! Just wanted to highlight it again for anyone looking at this.

Comment: ```$("#my-table>tr").each (index, element) =>```   

```=>``` or ```->``` !?

Answer (score 6):

You say

> Using something like `_this = this` outside the `.each` function and passing it around isn't a great solution, either, since I reference many class variables inside processRow.

This is the most efficient solution, though. JavaScript's `this` is a strange beast; you can keep it fixed inside of a nested function using the `=>` operator, as arnaud576875 sugests in his answer (which is elegant but inefficient), or you can copy `this` to another variable (which is efficient but inelegant). The choice is yours.

Note that some modern browsers support a `bind` method on every function, which is more efficient than CoffeeScript's `=>`. There's an open ticket to have `=>` use the native `bind` when available: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/1408

**Addendum:** Of course, a more efficient alternative than any of the above would be to write

```
for element, index in $('#my-table>tr')
  ...
```

which would also solve your `this` problem.

Comment: `for element, index in $('#my-table>tr')` is elegant and as you said more efficient, but is not the same as using `jquery.each()`, because with `for` there is no function binding. 
If you define another nested function (like binding a event listener), the inner defined vars will have only the value in the last iteration, causing strange behavior some times.

Comment: @tothemario Right, there's no scoping in a `for` loop, but the questioner's original example didn't involve any nested functions, so `for...in` is a perfectly good solution there (and, as stated, more efficient). If there are hundreds of `tr`s, the overhead of an unnecessary function call may be noticeable.

Answer (score 5):

Your code...

```
class foo
    @bar = 'bob loblaw'

    processRows: ->
        $("#my-table>tr").each ->
            id = $(this).attr("id")
            @processRow id

    processRow: (id) ->
        console.log @bar + id
```

Is transpiled to...

```
var foo;
foo = (function() {
  function foo() {}
  foo.bar = 'bob loblaw';
  foo.prototype.processRows = function() {
    return $("#my-table>tr").each(function() {
      var id;
      id = $(this).attr("id");
      return this.processRow(id);
    });
  };
  foo.prototype.processRow = function(id) {
    return console.log(this.bar + id);
  };
  return foo;
})();
```

Which has assumed much about about the current context that it is translating to. Unfortunately, since jQuery manages context, you'll have to be explicit or declare a reference to your class's `this`.

Incidentally, there are other issues with that generated code, take a look at this reduced case:

```
class foo
    @bar = 'bob loblaw'

    getBar: () ->
        @bar
```

Transpiles to:

```
var foo;
foo = (function() {
  function foo() {}
  foo.bar = 'bob loblaw';
  foo.prototype.getBar = function() {
    return this.bar;
  };
  return foo;
})();
```

The results of attempting to use this piece of code:

```
> foo.bar;
"bob loblaw"

> var f = new foo();
undefined

> f.getBar();
undefined
```

Your code seems to expect that `@bar` is an own property, but it's being created as a static property of the `foo` function

Comment: whoops, my bad! I forgot to include the constructor. So my code is actually more like: 

    class foo
        constructor: () ->
            @bar = 'bob loblaw'

--err, it won't format this with newlines, but you get the idea :). thanks for the response!